# Is $7^{8}+8^{9}+9^{7}+1$ a prime? (no computer usage allowed)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Prove or disprove that $$7^{8}+8^{9}+9^{7}+1$$ is a prime number, without using a computer.

I tried to transform $n^{n+1}+(n+1)^{n+2}+(n+2)^{n}+1$, unsuccessfully, no useful conclusion.

Comment: Checking mod 47 seems to work; there may be an easier way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is $2013^{2014}+2014^{2015}+2015^{2013}+1$ a prime? (usage of a computer not allowed)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866619/is-2013201420142015201520131-a-prime-usage-of-a-computer-not-all)

Comment: Checking primes less than sqrt of this number though for divisibility doesn't ensure a quick solution.

Comment: @deostroll, it is not a duplicate, different proof strategy should be employed...

Comment: whoever marked this question as a duplicate, spoiled the whole point of the question! connected two questions that are similar only in form... disaster... hope people think more before announcing "duplicates"!

Comment: Why do you expect there to be a reasonable way to do this by hand?

Comment: @Théophile Intuition.

Comment: @VividD: Consider that to be one of the drawbacks to writing overly sparse questions. How can you expect anyone else to treat the two questions as dissimilar if you yourself don't put any effort into making them dissimilar?

Comment: Have you attempted to factor $1 + 8^9$ or $1+ 9^7$ These both have clean factorizations  in fact $x^n + y^n$ for all odd N can be factorized over $Z$ I'm hoping somewhere along the line the number 47 pops out frequently enough to warrant the check mod 47

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715561/prove-or-disprove-99100100101101991-is-a-prime-number). Perhaps there is an elegant solution, since this question has shown up before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trial division mod $47$, as per the hint.

Firstly, for positive integer $a$, observe that $$a \equiv \overbrace{a \mod 50}^{\text{reduced residue}}+3\lfloor a/50\rfloor \pmod {47}.$$  This makes taking mod $47$s much easier.

- We compute $7^2=49 \equiv 2 \pmod {47}$.  So $7^8 \equiv 2^4 = 16 \pmod {47}$.
- We compute $8^2=64 \equiv 14+3 = 17 \pmod {47}$.  So $8^4 \equiv 17^2 = 289 \equiv 39+3 \times 5=54 \equiv 4+3=7 \pmod {47}.$  So $8^8 \equiv 7^2 = 49 \equiv 2 \pmod 7 \pmod {47}.$  So $8^9 \equiv 2 \times 8 = 16 \pmod {47}$.
- I happen to have memorized that $9^3=729$ (I used to set my alarm to 7:29am because it is equal to $3^6$).  So $9^3 \equiv 729 = 29+3 \times 14=71 \equiv 21+3=24 \pmod {47}$.  So $9^6 \equiv 24^2=576 \equiv 26+3 \times 11=59 \equiv 9+3=12 \pmod {47}$.  So $9^7=12 \times 9=108=8+3 \times 2=14 \pmod {47}$.

Finally $16+16+14+1=47 \equiv 0 \pmod {47}$.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Yes but but what would motivate reduction mod $47$ unless one had just set out to reduce mod everything up to $\sqrt{N}$?

Comment: Indeed, it's a cop out that way.  (I didn't feel like trial dividing $14$ more times.)

Comment: Still, there is some elegance and resourcefulness in this proof, even though 47 seems to be "known".

Comment: So now we know how to use modulo in case we know the answer. But what if it was a prime?

Comment: Patiently perform trial division using the $1440$ primes $\leq \sqrt{n}$?  It might take [three years of Sundays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Nelson_Cole) though.

Comment: @VividD The factor $47$ can be verified in a half-minute of mental arithmetic - see my answer.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones: The last line of that Wikipedia article ("Cole died alone") seems like vandalism to me.

Answer (score 3):

That $\,47\,$ is a factor can be verified by very easy mental arithmetic:

$\begin{eqnarray} 
{\rm mod}\ 47\!:\quad && 1+ \color{#c00}{7^8} +\, 8^9 +\ \color{#0a0}{9^7}\\
\equiv && 1+  \color{#c00}{2^4} + 2^{27} + \color{#0a0}{7\cdot 7^6\cdot 8^7}\quad {\rm by}\ \ \color{#0a0}{9\equiv 7\cdot 8},\ \ \color{#c00}{7^2\equiv 2}\\
\equiv&& 1+ 2^4 + 2^{27} + 7\cdot \color{#c00}{2^3}\cdot 2^{21}\\
\equiv&& 1+ 2^4 + 2^{4} +\ 7\cdot 2\,\equiv\, 0\quad {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}2^{23}\equiv (\color{#c00}{7^2})^{23}\equiv 7^{46}\equiv 1,\ \ \rm by\ little \ Fermat\\
\end{eqnarray}$